# How to add FB like + share AND also other Social Buttons on ALL pages and posts?

Tags: plugins, facebook, social-sharing

I tried many plugins but none of them have the following things so I guess I have to code it myself?

I just want to add under and above the content of blogpostings AND pages:
- the Facebook like and the share button
- other social media buttons like twitter
- email following option

=> none of all standard plugins I tried out had all this options included. So I ask you how to solve this problem? How to code it? I am a real coding-newbie (just can some simple html)

Thank you so much, tried it out now for hours...

Comment: do you have access to the Theme files?

Comment: Yes of course and with the help of stackoverflow I even modified functions.php in past successfully :)

Comment: Have you tried putting the code FB provides in footer.php?(given that all your templates use get_footer() ) or where exactly you want it to appear?

Comment: You can put above and below with https://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and easy-to-setup plugin for sharing button i ever used is [ShareThis](http://www.sharethis.com/get-sharing-tools/).

This light-weighted plugin is fully customizable and is compatible with any CMS/non-CMS website.

Simply head over to the link, include the `JS` file in your theme's header or footer, and then call the share buttons wherever you want. It will only take a moment.

This service also provides a specific plugin for WordPress, but if you have problem using it, just use the option for plain website and implement the code manually.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add Facebook like and share button in WordPress without using any plugin.
i had easily done this, just follow the this tutorial [Facebook like button](https://techinsidepc.com/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-wordpress/)

You will also get different tutorial on WordPress , Software Technology, Windows etc in this web

Comment: instead of posting external links that might not be available in the future, can you kindly edit your answer and add all the relevant details here? Thanks!

Comment: "link only answers" are usually not liked here. (What if the resource goes offline?) Could you elaborate in the answer the key aspects of what is told in the tutorial?